# Multiple outlets stopped working in the house

Tags: electrical, receptacle

Suddenly multiple outlets stopped working in Kitchen and living room.

Just some more info - I was using my insta pot in the kitchen when this happened but it wasn't the first time I used it. I unplugged it immediately and tried following couple of things

- No circuit breakers were tripped.
- Tried resetting the GFI but that wouldn't do anything.

There are few outlets not working in living room also not sure if they stopped working at the same time or something else as I don't use  formal living that frequently

Please guide me how should I troubleshoot this further.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are all the outlets that stopped working on the same circuit?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know. Is there any way I can figure it out?

Comment: Are you certain there isn't more than one GFI outlet in this circuit? If you have a GFI outlet at the beginning of the circuit and it trips, all the outlets downstream of it will not have power. You might want to check all of the outlets in your kitchen and living room to make sure there aren't any more GFI outlets. Make sure to "RESET" them all if you find any.

Comment: Sometimes circuit breakers are tripped even if they seem not to be tripped.  Try turning them off and on again, one at a time.  That would also be a time to make a list of what is controlled by each breaker.

Comment: I was sitting and suddenly heard some noise and went and tried resetting the GFI switch and it worked this time. The outlets which were not working earlier now seems to be working fine. Again in another 10 mins I heard the tripping sound and saw everything was off again including my refrigerator and all other outlets which were not working earlier. I checked the circuit breaker outside and everything looked good. Again turned off and ON the circuit breaker switches related to kitchen GFI but nothing seems to work now. Back to where I was.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel To answer your question all of them seems to be on the same circuit as after resetting the GFI switch it all started working once.

Comment: First check to see if any other circuit not working in the dwelling. You may have somehow lost a phase, but I am with everyone else on this. You need to isolate the problem. Is it one circuit or multiple circuits? Usually when you hear a noise something shorted out. Look for something that overheated or a blackened device. After that you are going to need  a meter and some electrical knowledge.